# How to setup separate counter metrics for different requests on an endpoint?

Tags: python, prometheus

I am new to Prometheus. I have a basic counter metric running for my endpoint. But this is a cumulative number of all requests made to this endpoint. I want to have a separate counter for each type of request. Understand that adding labels to counter will take care of it, I added labels to counter like below.

```
basic_counter = Counter('basic_counter','A basic counter.', ['app_name', 'endpoint'])
def metrics():
    basic_counter.labels('prom-python-app', 'localhost:5000').inc()
```

For example the endpoint has '/health' page. Upon visiting it, there should be count value for
localhost:5000 and localhost:5000/health on Prometheus metrics page. But the above code is returning only the basic_counter_total value. How can I create separate counter value for different pages visited in this endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can include a path in general for all kind of requests. You can follow below code:

```
basic_counter = Counter('basic_counter','A basic counter.', ['app_name', 'endpoint'])
def metrics(self):
    basic_counter.labels('prom-python-app', self.path).inc()
```

Comment: I  dont have a class. This is only function. Actually i am routing the app to '/metrics' endpoint. Then collect and expose metrics here in a format that prometheus can read. So I really cannot have a self.path.

Comment: ```from flask import Blueprint, Response, request
import http.server
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Counter, generate_latest

blueprint = Blueprint('metrics', __name__)

CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST = str('text/plain; version=0.0.4; charset=utf-8')

basic_counter = Counter('http_requests','Total number of requests to baseURL.', ['app_name', 'endpoint'])

@blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def metrics():
    basic_counter.labels('pron-python-app', 'localhost:5000').inc() 
    return Response(generate_latest(), mimetype=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST)```